# c# class naming standards/guidelines

Tags: c#, naming

Over the years I've used various naming conventions for services in my applications

for example:

```
[ClassName]Service  
[ClassName]Manager  
[ClassName]Factory  
[ClassName]Provider  
[ClassName]Helper
```

I generally only use the "Helper" suffix for utility classes that have no external dependencies.

However I find that there is a bit of a cross-over between the others, and wondered if there was any recommendations/standards/guidelines on what to use and when?

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to find guidelines on that, except for the obvious one: name your classes by their purpose. Manager, Factory, Provider and Service all mean different things. Your question seems to indicate they're interchangeable, they're not.

Comment: @svick, care to elaborate on this in an answer?

Comment: @Ben, I don't know what else to say. Just name your classes, so that it's obvious what they do. And I don't think what I said is worth an answer.

Comment: @svick well you make it sound like its absolutely obvious. I don't think it is. I could have a ProductManager that saves products or a ProductService that saves products. I could have a ConfigurationProvider or a ConfigurationFactory that generates a configuration. This is why I'm asking for an explanation.

Answer (score 8):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) has some advice on Type naming.

I also recommend reading [Framework Design Guidelines](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321246756) book for a more detailed discussion on naming and lots of extra design advice.